# How to fix? Error 500: No WSGI daemon process called... (Apache/ Django)

Tags: django, apache

I have an internal Server Error 500 on my Django Server. When I check the error.log, I get the following error:

```
No WSGI daemon process called "..." has been configured: "..."
```

I hope someone can help me to fix this Error.

Here is my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin ADMIN
        ServerName DOMAIN   

        ErrorLog /home/USER/PROJECT/site/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/PROJECT/PROJECT/site/logs/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/USER/PROJECT/static
        <Directory /home/USER/PROJECT/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/USER/PROJECT/src/social>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess PROJECT python-path=/home/USER/PROJECT/ python-home=/home/USER/PROJECT/VIRTUALENV
        WSGIProcessGroup PROJECT
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/USER/PROJECT/src/social/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

move your project path from **/home/USER/PROJECT** to **/var/www/PROJECT**

make sure you are chmod project folder --> **sudo chmod -R 777 /project**

if not work give your email to me for contact

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# edit all /home/USER/PROJECT to /var/www/PROJECT

        ServerAdmin ADMIN
        ServerName DOMAIN   

        ErrorLog /home/USER/PROJECT/site/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/PROJECT/PROJECT/site/logs/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/USER/PROJECT/static
        <Directory /home/USER/PROJECT/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/USER/PROJECT/src/social> # here put path of where wsgi.py existing folder
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess PROJECT python-path=/home/USER/PROJECT/ python-home=/home/USER/PROJECT/VIRTUALENV
        WSGIProcessGroup PROJECT
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/USER/PROJECT/src/social/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```